Constant cancellation model for volume of LOB queues
I have been reading Jean-Philippe Bouchaud's book on stochastic models of LOB queues in Chapter 5, which starts with the simplest model. In this model, market/limit/cancel orders are assumed to be of as small as a lot size and behave as independent Poisson processes with coefficients $\mu, \lambda, \nu$, respectively.
In section 5.3, probability $P(V, t)$ of observing LOB queue of volume $V$ satisfies the following equation:
$$\frac{\partial P(V, t)}{\partial t} = -(\lambda + \mu + \nu) P(V, t) + \lambda P(V-1, t) + (\mu + \nu) P(V + 1, t) + J(t) \rho (V)$$
where $J(t)$ is a rate of depleting queue at time $t$ and $\rho(V)$ is a distribution of the next price volume after the depletion.
With my limited understanding of differential equations and such, I tried to convince the above equation as follows:
$$P(V, t + dt) = J(t) dt \rho(V) + \lambda dt P(V-1, t) + (\mu + \nu) dt P(V+1, t) + (1 - J(t) - \lambda - \mu - \nu) dt P(V, t) + O(dt^2)$$
with "law of total probability". However, with the above we get a slightly different equation (omitting $O(dt^2)$ stuff):
$$\frac{\partial P(V, t)}{\partial t} = -(\lambda + \mu + \nu + J(t)) P(V, t) + \lambda P(V-1, t) + (\mu + \nu) P(V + 1, t) + J(t) \rho (V)$$
Could you please help me out with where I might be wrong? Also, I would greatly appreciate if you could point in references to learn more about arguing on the above rigorously.

The queue only depletes if V reaches 0, so J(t) is in fact the flux at V=0

I figured my application of "law of total probability" is wrong. It should be applied as $P(V, t +dt) = \sum_{V'} P(V', t) [P(V,t)\text{ given volume is }V'\text{ at t}] $ and then everything makes sense.
